# setText() is not working inside a try statement Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a program that reads a text file, and then applies the 2d array that is written with the file to several methods that I have previously created.

```
    openFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int[][] myBoard;
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int r = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileLabel.setText("<html>" + fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() + "<html/>");

                try {
                    File file = new File(String.valueOf(fc.getSelectedFile()));
                    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
                    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
                    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = reader.nextLine();
                        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Character ch : line.toCharArray()) {
                            array.add(Integer.parseInt(ch.toString()));
                        }
                        arrays.add(array);
                     }
                    reader.close();
                    myBoard = new int[arrays.size()][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> save = arrays.get(i);

                        int[] copy = new int[save.size()];
                        for (int j = 0; j < save.size(); j++) {
                            copy[j] = save.get(j);
                        }
                        myBoard[i] = copy;
                    }
                    myField.setText("Loading...");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    myField.setText("");
                    char[][] prettyBoard = render(myBoard);
                    while (true) {
                        myBoard = nextState(myBoard);
                        prettyBoard = render(myBoard);
                        for (char[] row : prettyBoard) {
                            for (char el : row) {
                                myField.append(el + " ");
                            }
                            myField.append("\n");
                        }
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                        myField.setText("");
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException | InterruptedException q) {
                    q.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                fileLabel.setText("Operation cancelled by user");
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code I currently have. Everything is working properly, other than this section:

```
myField.setText("Loading...");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                myField.setText("");
                char[][] prettyBoard = render(myBoard);
                while (true) {
                    myBoard = nextState(myBoard);
                    prettyBoard = render(myBoard);
                    for (char[] row : prettyBoard) {
                        for (char el : row) {
                            myField.append(el + " ");
                        }
                        myField.append("\n");
                    }
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                    myField.setText("");
                }
```

Even if I remove all the extra stuff, and just try to call myField.setText("Loading") there are issues. When I launch the program the GUI launches how it is intended, but when I select a file to load it just freezes. I can no longer exit on close, and the file path does not appear in the label I created.

Thank you for any help you can provide :).

Comment: Don't use "while (true)". This code is executing on the EDT and is an infinite loop and will prevent the GUI from responding to events and repainting itself. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr thank you very much! What would you suggest instead?

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) lesson from _Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing_ which is part of Oracle's java tutorials.